# Need to migrate Oracle transaction data to Azure SQL

Tags: oracle, azure-sql-database, database-migration, database-replication

There is one scenario where in our target is to migrate oracle database to Azure SQL DB.

Currently I am evaluating multiple options to migrate the existing Oracle Db to the Azure SQL DB, for the same reason I could not decide how to handle this situation where in the source DB i.e. Oracle is having transaction data which is a kind of incremental load.
Should this can be handled with mere replication of DB? or performing some data migration steps would help me ? Here i can think of earlier approach as easier approach where in i need not to worry about the transaction updates happening inside the data.

Considering this which utility i should use to perform this kind of activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate your Oracle database to Azure using [Oracle Golden Gate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/oracle/configure-oracle-golden-gate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json) as a way to migrate your Oracle database to Azure SQL. [Striim](https://www.striim.com/) seems to be another good tools to move your database to Azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use the SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Oracle.

SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Oracle consists of a client application that you use to perform a migration from Oracle to SQL Server and Azure SQL DB. It also contains an extension pack that supports data migration and the use of Oracle system functions in your migrated databases.

SSMA can converts the transaction processing:
[image]
For more details, you can see:[SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/installing-ssma-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017)

Hope this helps!